# Determine all square sub matrices of a given NxN matrix in C++

Tags: c++, matrix, code-generation, submatrix

GIven an NxN square matrix, I would like to determine all possible square sub matrices by removing equal number of rows and columns.

In order to determine all possible 2x2 matrices I need to loop 4 times. Similarly for 3x3 matrices I need to loop 6 times and so on. Is there a way to generate code in C++ so that the code for the loops is generated dynamically? I have checked some answers related to code generation in C++, but most of them use python in it. I have no idea regarding python. So, is it possible to write code to generate code in C++?

Comment: You can generate a lot of code if you use templates. If you post the code that you would write manually for 2x2 sub-matrices and 3x3 sub-matrices, you might get help on how to generalize that for  MxM sub-matrices.

Comment: What is the algorithm you use to determine all possible 2x2 sub matrices and why do you need to generate code dynamically?

Comment: You know, if `N` gets larger, the number of sub-matrices would exponentially grow. Why do you need _all of them_?

Comment: @Bob__ I first select two columns and then two rows. Selecting two columns need 2 loops and for rows 2 loops. That's how I get 4 loops. Basically the four iterators of 4 loops are for 2 rows and 2 colums which form the 2x2 matrix

Comment: @polfosol I would like to know whether any of them are singular. Please answer if you have a better way to determine if any of the sub matrices is singular Thanks.

Comment: @vineel The general problem is way more complicated than it looks. I have to give it more thoughts, but sadly I don't have enough time right now.

Answer (score 1):

If I get what you are saying, you mean you require M loops to choose M rows, and M loops for M columns for an M x M sub matrix, 1 <= M <= N

You don't need 2*M loops to do this. No need to dynamically generate code with an ever-increasing number of loops!

Essentially, you need to "combine" all possible combinations of i_{1}, i_{2}, ..., i_{M} and j_{1}, j_{2}, ..., j_{M} such that 1 <= i_{1} < i_{2} < ... < i_{M} <= N (and similarly for j)

If you have all possible combinations of all such i_{1}, ..., i_{M} you are essentially done.

Say for example you are working with a 10 x 10 matrix and you require 4 x 4 sub matrices.

Suppose you selected rows {1, 2, 3, 4} and columns {1, 2, 3, 4} initially. Next select column {1, 2, 3, 5}. Next {1, 2, 3, 6} and so on till {1, 2, 3, 10}. Next select {1, 2, 4, 5}, next {1, 2, 4, 6} and so on till you reach {7, 8, 9, 10}. This is one way you could generate all ("10 choose 4") combinations in a sequence.

Go ahead, write a function that generates this sequence and you are done. It can take as input M, N, current combination (as an array of M values) and return the next combination.

You need to call this sequence to select the next row and the next column.

I have put this a little loosely. If something is not clear I can edit to update my answer.

---

Edit:

I will be assuming loop index starts from 0 (the C++ way!). To elaborate the algorithm further, given one combination as input the next combination can be generated by treating the combination as a "counter" of sorts (except that no digit repeats).

Disclaimer : I have not run or tested the below snippet of code. But the idea is there for you to see. Also, I don't use C++ anymore. Bear with me for any mistakes.

```
// Requires M <= N as input, (N as in N x N matrix)
void nextCombination( int *currentCombination, int M, int N ) {
    int *arr = currentCombination;
    for( int i = M - 1; i >= 0; i-- ) {
        if( arr[i] < N - M + i ) {
            arr[i]++;
            for( i = i + 1, i < M; i++ ) {
                arr[i] = arr[i - 1] + 1;
            }
            break;
        }
    }

}

// Write code for Initialization: arr = [0, 1, 2, 3]
nextCombination( arr, 4, 10 );
// arr = [0, 1, 2, 4]

// You can check if the last combination has been reached by checking if arr[0] == N - M + 1. Please incorporate that into the function if you wish.
```

---

Edit:

> Actually I want to check singularity of all possible sub matrices. My approach is to compute all submatrices and then find their determinants. How ever after computing the determinant of 2x2 matrices , I'll store them and use while computing determinants of 3x3 matrices. And so on. Can you suggest me a better approach. I have no space and time constraints. – vineel

A straight-forward approach using what you suggest is to index the determinants based on the the rows-columns combination that makes a sub matrix. At first store determinants for 1 x 1 sub matrices in a hash map (basically the entries themselves).

So the hash map would look like this for the 10 x 10 case
    
    `{ 
        "0-0" : arr_{0, 0}, 
        "0-1" : arr_{0, 1},
        . 
        . 
        . 
        "1-0" : arr_{1, 0}, 
        "1-1" : arr_{1, 1},
        .
        .
        .
        "9-9" : arr_{9, 9}
    }`

When M = 2, you can calculate determinant using the usual formula (the determinants for 1 x 1 sub matrices having been initialized) and then add to the hash map. The hash string for a 2 x 2 sub matrix would look something like `1:3-2:8` where the row indices in the original 10 x 10 matrix are 1,3 and the column indices are 2, 8. In general, for m x m sub matrix, the determinant can be determined by looking up all necessary (already) computed (m - 1) x (m - 1) determinants - this is a simple hash map lookup. Again, add the determinant to hash map once calculated.

Of course, you may need to slightly modify the nextCombination() function - it currently assumes row and column indices run from 0 to N - 1.

On another note, since all sub matrices are to be processed starting from 1 x 1, you don't need something like a nextCombination() function. Given a 2 x 2 matrix, you just need to select one more row and column to form a 3 x 3 matrix. So you need to select one row-index (that's not part of the row indices that make the 2 x 2 sub matrix) and similarly one column-index. But doing this for every 2 x 2 matrix will generate duplicate 3 x 3 matrices - you need to think of some way to eliminate duplicates. One way to avoid duplicates is by choosing only such row/column whose index is greater than the highest row/column index in the sub matrix.

Again I have loosely defined the idea. You can build upon it.

Comment: Just to add - since there are 10C4 combinations for row and for columns each, the total number of sub matrices would be (10C4)^2

Comment: OT, there isn't Mathjax in SO, but you can use i **<sub>** 1 **</sub>** for subscripts...

Comment: @PrashanthPuranik But how to generate those 10C4 combinations without using loops? If you think that I haven't got it the right way, please elaborate your answer. Thanks

Comment: My point is - you don't *need to* use 2*M loops to generate the combinations. The algorithm I have mentioned is one way to generate the combinations of rows/columns in a sequence.

Comment: I made an edit to include the algorithm to generate the next combination (disclaimer added)

Comment: @PrashanthPuranik Thanks a lot, I have written the code, it works. I will think over the algo. Actually I want to check singularity of all possible sub matrices. My approach is to compute all submatrices and then find their determinants. How ever after computing the determinant of 2x2 matrices , I'll store them and use while computing determinants of  3x3 matrices. And so on. Can you suggest me a better approach. I have no space and time constraints.

Comment: Hey, it works like a counter - something like a fuel station/gas station/petrol bunk filling machine. The digits get incremented starting from the right and when you hit the max digit at a position (9 for decimal system we use!) it increments the digit to the left and resets the currently considered digit to 0 (minimum value digit) - except in our case we don't "reset" to zero, we reset based on some other logic - this is what the inner for loop does you can figure out :) - it is somewhat complicated to explain in words.